# How to estimate integral by using weighted Gauss Quadrature

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

If you are given a weighted Gauss quadrature of:

$$\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=\bigg(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\sqrt6}{36}\bigg)\cdot f\bigg(\frac{6-\sqrt6}{10}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt6}{36}\bigg)\cdot f\bigg(\frac{6+\sqrt6}{10}\bigg)$$

How can you estimate a simple integral, such as:

$$\int_{0}^{1} x\sin(x)dx$$

Comment: $f(x) = \sin(x)$

Answer (score 2):

If you're **given** :

$$\int_{0}^{1}xf(x)dx=\bigg(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{\sqrt6}{36}\bigg)\cdot f\bigg(\frac{6-\sqrt6}{10}\bigg)+\bigg(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{\sqrt6}{36}\bigg)\cdot f\bigg(\frac{6+\sqrt6}{10}\bigg)$$

the simply for the integral :

$$\int_0^1x\sin xdx$$

take $f(x)=\sin x$ and then you'll have the initial form of the given expression.

Calculate :

$$f\bigg(\frac{6-\sqrt6}{10}\bigg)=\sin\bigg(\frac{6-\sqrt6}{10}\bigg)$$

$$f\bigg(\frac{6+\sqrt6}{10}\bigg) = \sin\bigg(\frac{6+\sqrt6}{10}\bigg)$$

and the rest of the fractions with a calculator and you'll have your estimation.

Comment: Thats really all there is too it? It looks more challenging on the face, i assume. So we'll compute the RHS to get the approximate estimation for the integral of 0 to 1 x sin(x).

Comment: @AggrawalPuja Yeah, that's all there is to it. The approximation (Gauss Quadrature) that you're given, is for any function $f(x)$ (just like other numerical methods regarding integration, such as the trapezoid rule, Simpon's rule etc). Since the integral you mentioned has the same "form" as the one in the quadrature expression given, all you have to do is let $f(x)=\sin x$ and calculate the RHS with the values mentioned.

Comment: thanks for the response. That makes a lot of sense...It seems that the formula is exact for 1,x,x^2....x^n based on your comment. What does x^n represent, though?

Comment: @AggrawalPuja Wait, where did I mention anything about $x^n$ ?

Comment: you didn't, but I was just observing that this formula seems to be exact for 1,x,x^2,x^n...and I was just trying to figure out what x^n represented in that context.

Comment: @AggrawalPuja I still do not understand, how does $x^n$ get involved here ? Also, what do you mean by "exact" ?

Comment: If you have f(x) = 1,x,x^2,x^n, it seems the weighted Gauss equation would be exact for the f(x)=1,x,x^2,x^.

Comment: @AggrawalPuja Do you mean an exact differential equation ? Because this is the only thing that your phrase resembles me to.